# Contradictory units for moments of inertia

Tags: applied-mechanics

I'm looking at a motor datasheet where the moment of inertia is specified in units of "oz in sec^2". I would think that inertia should have dimensions of mass * length^2.

I did some further Googling and found that some automatic unit conversion calculators ([example](http://www.numberfactory.com/nf%20inertia.htm)) let you convert between seemingly contradictory units - the site I've linked lists both kg-m^2 to kg-m-s^2 as acceptable units for moments of inertia. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I spent some time searching on this one, and surprise surprise, Imperial units strike again!

The good old ["pounds-force pounds-mass issue"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(force)) masked with ounces. This is why any calculation more involved than sizing a pulley should be done in metric, lol.

[Oriental Motor- Basics of motor control](http://www.orientalmotor.com/technology/articles/motor-sizing-calculations.html), explains the following:

> Units of Measure for Moment Inertia
>
> The units of inertia are commonly used in two ways, oz-in<sup>2</sup> and oz-in-sec<sup>2</sup>. The former includes gravity, the latter only mass.
>
> Theoretically, inertia is factor of mass so it should not include gravity, however, practically we can not easily measure mass on the earth.
>
> Oriental Motor commonly provides inertia in oz-in<sup>2</sup>. Then, when we calculate the Acceleration Torque in Torque Calculation we divide the total the total inertia by the gravity from.
>
> Gravity = 386 in/sec<sup>2</sup>
>
> - oz-in<sup>2</sup> = Inertia based on weight
> - oz-in-sec<sup>2</sup> = inertia based on mass
>
> Calculation for oz-in<sup>2</sup> to oz-in-sec<sup>2</sup>
>
> [image]

So an oz-in-sec<sup>2</sup> **does** exist because it's an ounce-force not an ounce-mass.

A kg-m-s<sup>2</sup> **does not** exist, because kg is mass not force. You could convert oz-in-sec<sup>2</sup> with Newtons, but I wouldn't even go there, lol.

The best course of action is to follow Oriental Motor's guide to get to oz-in<sup>2</sup>. Then convert to metric kg-m<sup>2</sup> and don't look back ;-)